# Navigation Tab Bar Controller to UIView Controller?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad

I am using tab bar controller and i want to push uiview controller over tab bar controller. but i don't know how we push UIView controller over Tab Bar Controller. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to embed a navigation controller in your tab bar controller screen where you want the push set up to work

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading your question right, you want to push a view controller over another view controller which is currently displaying tabs.

In this case, I believe you would need a UINavigationController as your root view controller.  Inside this navigation controller, you would initially push a UITabController with it's associated view controllers per tab.  When it's time to push another view controller over the tab controller, create an instance of the view controller to push and use the following code:

[self.navigationController pushViewController:newViewController animated:YES];

This will push the new view controller over the existing TabController that is currently being displayed.

Answer (score 0):

The question is little vague Hence I will add the two way to push to another view controller we use in common. 
From navigation controller : You just need to create an UIButton in the navigation controller and then control + drag the button to another view controller to create a push feature to another screen in storyboard. 
From Tab view Controller : Similarly, control key + drag the tab bar item in the tab bar controller to another UIView controller in the story board. Then chose 'show' option to create a push to another UIview controller screen. 
Hope this helps.

Tab Bar controller is different and Navigation Bar controller is different.

And as Pittmaster says, your navigation view controller should be root view controller.